# Android Emulator can't edit hardware

Tags: android, android-emulator

Recently I updated to API 12 . Besides the problem with not founding the emulator when the SDK is installed to C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk , which I solved by moving the android-sdk to C:\ , I have another problem: when creating a new emulator, I can't add new hardware to it from the Eclipse wizard, the emulator has only "Abstracted LCD density" and "Max VM application heap size" and when I press "New..." nothing happens. Do you have the same problem? How do I solve it ?

Comment: I just tried it, and I now have the same problem. I guess there's a bug API 12.

Comment: what a piece. crazy that they can release stuff like that and get away with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a solution to your problem. You can edit the `config.ini` file of an AVD by hand.
Go to the folder where your AVD is stored (usually in the folder `<userprofile>\.android\avd\<avdname>\`)
and open the config.ini file in a text editor. The text editor should be capable of reading files in unix formatting (e.g. Windows Wordpad).

Below are some example hardware properties you can add:

- hw.sdCard=yes
- sdcard.size=256M
- hw.audioInput=yes
- hw.audioOutput=yes
- hw.camera=yes
- hw.camera.maxVerticalPixels=480
- hw.camera.maxHorizontalPixels=640
- hw.sensors.proximity=yes
- hw.gps=yes
- hw.accelerometer=yes
- hw.gyroscope=yes

Make sure you close the Android AVD Manager before making any changes to the config.ini.

**EDIT:**
A strange thing just happened. The "new" button in the Android SDK and AVD manager has just started to work again on my computer. The only thing I did was try out my own solution described above and quit and restart the manager. So maybe only a restart is necessary!?

Answer (score 0):

I was just experiencing the same problem.  Haven't fixed it yet but have found that the New Hardware button works outside of Eclipse but not inside for me.